# Inserting array value into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array `$playernames` which holds different player names. Im trying to extract the values and upload them to a database one query per time, as such:

```
for ($i=0; sizeof($playername) > $i; $i++)
{
    $name = $playername[$i];
    $query = mysql_query(
        "INSERT INTO `team`(`fixture_id`,`player_name`
    ) 
    VALUES ($id, '$name')") or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

However what now happens now is after every query in the loop the data gets overwrited in the name colum of database. After execution when I open the DB only the name of the last player contained in the array is displayed.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.
(sorry if this question touches on duplicate but I've not seen a clear explanation regarding above problem)

Comment: you can alter your table and make the fixture_id to auto-increment , so u will care about sending it to the DB anymore .. mysql will handle it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing/changing the value of the variable `$id` for `fixture_id`.

Hence, it is taking the default value.

If your `fixture_id` is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`, modify your query as:

```
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `team`(`player_name`) 
    VALUES ('$name')") or die(mysql_error());
```

And `fixture_id` will take automatically incremented value.

Or set `$id` from the array `$playername`.

Also, modify the statement:

`for ($i=0; sizeof($playername) > $i; $i++)`

To:

```
$len = sizeof($playername);
for ($i=0; $len > $i; $i++)
```

As you are calling a PHP function too many times (equal to the array length), this may be a performance hit.

By doing this, we are using a variable `$len` instead of many function calls.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `fixture_id` in your SQL, provided by the variable `$id` never changes. Hence, each query is overwriting the values of the previous one. You probably need to add some logic to change `$id` in each loop iteration as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$id` value is not set or is the same all the time, you probably wanted to use `$i` instead like:

```
for ($i=0; sizeof($playername) > $i; $i++)
{
    $name = $playername[$i];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `team`(`fixture_id`,`player_name`) 
    VALUES ($i, '$name')") or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

Also you can create auto-increment column and then just insert it like this:

```
foreach($playername as $name){

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `team`(`fixture_id`,`player_name`) 
            VALUES ('', '$name')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

where `fixture_id` is automatically incremented  in mysql